# Select box I need it to default to first option after click on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a select box with a list of option that gets populated from a google sheet that all works fine but what i need is for the select box to go back to the first option after I click submit. Here is my select box code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    <?
      var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GerAhvhytiKKrOUCTiavDuPRJAT9uYYRje2d85ED3").getSheetByName("Data");
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
      var myRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B"+lastRow); 
      var data    = myRange.getValues();
    ?>

  </script>  

<div class="row"> 
   <div class="input-field col s4 l4">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">person</i>
     <select id="Emp" >
       <option value=""  disabled selected>Select your name</option> <!--THIS IS THE OPTION I NEED AFTER SUBMIT-->
       <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
        <option ><?!= data[i] ?></option>
       <? } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

When I click on submit I have a script that clear all the value and goes back to the top of the form but i can't seem to get this select box to go back to the first option that says Select your name. I've tried adding this to my script that clear the other field but it's not working

```
     document.getElementById("Emp").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: How are you submitting the data?

Comment: to a google sheet using this 


        function userSubmit(userInfo){
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1M4AGV0YFJvC-ykOSYo4YYFEKCkOVHkcR1mWQr5_tc');
    var ws =  ss.getSheetByName('Request');
    var ws =  ss.getSheetByName('Request');
    ws.appendRow([new Date()
                ,userInfo.prefDate2
                ,userInfo.days
                ,userInfo.Emp
       
                ])

};